# How to assign dataset in Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to assign dataset attributes with Object.assign()? For example like this:

```
Object.assign(document.getElementById('test'), {
    id: 'test',
    dataset: { mydata: 'test' },
})
```

**Update:** at least this works for assigning multiple dataset:

```
Object.assign(document.getElementById('test').dataset, {
    mydata: 'test',
})
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

The `dataset` property is readonly so you can't overwrite it.

If you could, then your attempt will break it because the value needs to be a [DOMStringMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap) object and not a plain object.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Maybe you know an alternative for assigning multiple HTML attributes including dataset?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Element.setAttribute()` function for adding `HTMLElement` attribtue. Check it out-

```js
const el = document.getElementById('test');
const dataset = {name: 'john', age: 34, gender: 'male'};

for (const prop in dataset) {
    el.setAttribute(`data-${prop}`, dataset[prop]);
}
```

- Here an object `dataset` with data name and value is declared.
- Iterate throw the object using `for ... in` loop and using `setAttribute` function set the data attribtue.

Comment: I was hoping for something without the need of a loop, but thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with using the `dataset` property or `Object.assign` the OP had? This is more complex, but doesn't solve the problem.